# Is there a way to use the sep="" function with an inputed string

Tags: python, input, printing, separator

I have been trying to use the separator function with a message that uses the input function, but it seems the that the separator function does not work and it only prints out the inputed phrase. For ex. I use sep="..." and would expect my inputed phrase to print out "This...Is...My...Inputed...Phrase" but instead I receive "This is my inputed phrase".

```
# Asking for user to input any phrase or word they want
user_phrase = input('What is the phrase you want to print?')

# using the seperator function to seperate the inputed phrase by the desired users choice of string.
print(user_phrase, sep='...')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sep` parameter is used when you pass in more than one argument to `print()` like:

```
print("some string", "some other string", sep="...")
# some string...some other string
```

To get your desired output, you need to turn your single string into multiple strings. `split()` will do that. Then you need to turn those into individual arguments to `print()`. You can do that like this:

```
s = "This is my inputed phrase"
print(*s.split(), sep='...')
# This...is...my...inputed...phrase
```